# Splitting paragraph text and calculating average word count

Tags: python, mapreduce

```
value =
1|a b c d
1|b c d

2|a b b g h
```

I’m trying to establish an ID for each of the paragraphs (1,2) as shown above, and expecting a result like 1: `(a,b,c,d,b,c,d)`

Trying to use (in Python)
Id, result = value.strip().split(“|”)

However it fails saying expecting 2 results and getting 1.

Comment: Is your code iterating over value 1 line at a time? If so, the problem is that the 3rd line is blank, so `split` doesn't return two items. You need to check that two items are returned before assigning the results to Id and result.

Comment: Thanks Craig! Yes it’s probably due to the blank line- how can we tell the code to skip the third row.

Comment: I’m so sorry, I’m quite new to this

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage the blank lines, you can either use an `if` statement to check that 2 items are returned, or you can use a `try/except` to catch the error and handle the blank lines separately.

#### Testing for correct number of items

```
temp = value.strip().split(“|”)
if len(temp) == 2:
    Id, result = temp
    
    # do the rest of your processing here\
else:
    pass  # or do something for the blank line
```

#### Using exception handling

```
try:
    Id, result = value.strip().split(“|”)
except ValueError:
    pass  # or do something for the blank line
```